# AI good practices in combining tasks?

Tags: pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I'm designing a neural network (pytorch) that accomplishes two different, but entangled, tasks. One is very difficult, one is very easy. While training two different models (two trainings, two set of parameters,...) can crack both of the problems independently, when combined, the hard task fails, no matter what I do. I would like to understand why and if there's a way around it

Example: Let's say that I would like, given a picture, to:

1. determine if there's a dog in the picture (easy)
2. get a new picture where the dog has a red hat (if there's a dog) or a cat is placed coherently in the picture (very hard)

Both of this problems are not impossible, however if I ask the NN to crack them simultaneously only the easy one is successful. Why?

My guesses are the following:

- the first task makes it so that the overfitting in the validation dataset is reached before the second task is handled
- the cost function changes drastically, so that the features given by the second task are basically noise when compared with the first one's.

I know I could just split the tasks, but that's not what is required from me at the moment

what do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your task/network/data, it's difficult to give advice on your problem specifically. However, generally speaking, the interaction between different tasks can vary. Sometimes they can complement each other and boost learning, sometimes not. If you're interested, three subfields of Machine Learning that investigate this are Transfer Learning (for transferring knowledge from one to domain to another), Curriculum Learning (for transferring knowledge from one task to another in sequence) and Multitask Learning (for learning multiple tasks simultaneously).

Is the input data the same for both tasks? Does the network need to learn them in sequence or simultaneously?

Your suggestions may be right - the network might get stuck in a local minimum of the easy task, and not be able to then learn the difficult task. That sounds as if they are quite different tasks, and don't share overlapping solutions? If that's not true, and they should share parts of the solutions, perhaps the learning algorithm could be tuned (slower learning rate, different ratio of loss functions, different set-up of combining the tasks (sequence/simultaneous/semi-simultaneous).

Comment: Dear, they do share the same input and they should be accomplished simultaneously! Unfortunately I shouldn't share more details as per some sort of loose NDA with what is technically my employer. Thank you!

Comment: Ok well have a look at multitask learning literature, and see if you can find similar cases! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to simply detach the simple task from the hard one, and have the simple task re-use intermediate outputs from earlier layers of the hard task. The simple task can have its loss flow backward only through its independent layers, without interfering with common early feature-extracting layers.

Aside from multi-task learning, this kind of challenge is also seen in actor-critic models in reinforcement learning.

E.g. in "Deep Reinforcement Learning In Action" [Chapter 5](https://livebook.manning.com/book/deep-reinforcement-learning-in-action/chapter-5/v-6/78) page 127:

> The second path is the critic head, which applies a linear layer and ReLU to the output of layer 2, but notice we call y.detach(), which detaches the y node from the graph and thus the critic loss won’t backpropagate and modify the weights in layer 1 and 2, only the actor will cause the weights to be modified. This is not a crucial feature but it improves the training time a bit by reducing the conflict between what the actor and critic want. With two-headed models, it often makes sense to make one head the dominant head and control most of the parameters by detaching the other head from the first several layers.

This relates to the code listing 5.5 also found [here](https://github.com/DeepReinforcementLearning/DeepReinforcementLearningInAction/blob/master/Chapter%205/Ch5_book.ipynb)

```py
class ActorCritic(nn.Module): #B
def __init__(self):
    super(ActorCritic, self).__init__()
    self.l1 = nn.Linear(4,25)
    self.l2 = nn.Linear(25,50)
    self.actor_lin1 = nn.Linear(50,2)
    self.l3 = nn.Linear(50,25)
    self.critic_lin1 = nn.Linear(25,1)
def forward(self,x):
    x = F.normalize(x,dim=0)
    y = F.relu(self.l1(x))
    y = F.relu(self.l2(y))
    actor = F.log_softmax(self.actor_lin1(y),dim=0) #C
    c = F.relu(self.l3(y.detach()))
    critic = torch.tanh(self.critic_lin1(c)) #D
    return actor, critic #E
```